# Pyparsing: alternation of whitespaces and line starts

Tags: pyparsing

Using pyparsing, I would like to get a list of tokens that are either preceded by a whitespace or are at the start of the line. But I am struggling just to find both whitespaces and line starts, never mind the actual token:

```py
from pyparsing import LineStart, MatchFirst, Regex, Or, White


WS = White(" ")
NL = LineStart()
# Same result with:
# NL = Regex("(?m)^")

data = """
Line one.
Line two.
"""
parser = MatchFirst((WS, NL))
# Same result with:
# parser = WS | NL (equivalent to MatchFirst)
# parser = Or((Ws, NL))
# parser = WS ^ NL (equivalent to Or)

result = parser.searchString(data)
print(f'{len(result)} matches.')
# 3 matches.
# Should be 5 matches.

parser = NL
result = parser.searchString(data)
print(f'{len(result)} matches.')
# 3 matches.
# Correct.

parser = WS
result = parser.searchString(data)
print(f'{len(result)} matches.')
# 2 matches.
# Correct.
```

The `data` string has 2 spaces and 3 line starts, and if I use just `WS` (whitespace) or `NL` (line start), the parser does find the correct number of occurrences.

However, when using alternation with `Or`, `|`,  or `MatchFirst`, only the line starts are found, not the two whitespace characters.

I wonder if am I overlooking something or if whitespace matching doesn't work as expected. If I look for literals instead of whitespace, I have no trouble finding both the literals and the line starts.